# Grepping and only sending e-mail if something found

Tags: linux, bash, cron, grep

```
#!/bin/bash
( /usr/src/chkrootkit-$VERSION/chkrootkit ) | # Binary
grep 'INFECTED|Vulnerable' | # Only get found issues
/bin/mail -s 'CHROOTKIT Weekly Run ($SERVERNAME)' $EMAIL # Send EMail
```

This still sends e-mails even if nothing is found.

What would be a way to only send if something is grepped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This maybe...

Simply use `-E` switch in mail command:

```
man -Pcol\ -b mail | grep empty
     -E      Don't send messages with an empty body.


#!/bin/bash
( /usr/src/chkrootkit-$VERSION/chkrootkit ) | # Binary
grep 'INFECTED|Vulnerable' | # Only get found issues
/bin/mail -E -s 'CHROOTKIT Weekly Run ($SERVERNAME)' $EMAIL # Send EMail
```

or place your check in a `crontab` for automatic processing, for ex once a day:

```
@daily  ( /usr/src/chkrootkit-$VERSION/chkrootkit ) | grep 'INFECTED|Vulnerable'
```

Cron will send a mail if command output something.

#### But, after re-reading this

If there is no need to *forward* any part of the mail in the alert, there is no need to use the *pipe* `|`.

So you could use *condition* in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
( /usr/src/chkrootkit-$VERSION/chkrootkit ) | # Binary
    grep -q 'INFECTED|Vulnerable' &&
    /bin/mail -s 'CHROOTKIT Weekly Run ($SERVERNAME)' $EMAIL
```

The `-q` switch to `grep` ensure to stay quiet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the common GNU Mailutils 2.2 version of mail uses the -E switch to execute a command and there's no equivalent to the "Don't send messages with an empty body" switch as you describe.

Comment: I'm speaking about [BSD's mail, Mail, mailx -- send and receive mail utility](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mail&sektion=1). (Not [GNU Mailutils](http://mailutils.org/) ;-)

Comment: Ok, second part use `grep -q` instead of `mail -E`, this could do the job.

Answer (score 4):

For GNU Mailutils, you can do something like this with **-E'set nonullbody'**:

```
grep whatever wherever | mailx -E'set nonullbody' -s EMAIL_SUBJECT your_email_address@example.com
```

See http://mailutils.org/manual/html_section/mail.html:
nullbody

> Type: Boolean
> Default: True
>
> Controls whether mail accepts messages with an empty body. The default value, true, means such messages are sent, and a warning (traditionally saying ‘Null message body; hope that's ok’) is displayed. The text of the warning can be set using nullbodymsg variable (see below).
>
> If nullbody is unset, mail will silently ignore such messages. This can be useful in ‘crontab’ files, to avoid sending mails when nothing important happens. For example, the ‘crontab’ entry below will send mail only if the utility some-prog outputs something on its standard output or error:

Just put the above in cron for some schedule:

```
*/5 * * * * some-prog 2>&1 | /bin/mail -E'set nonullbody' -s 'Periodic synchronization'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
( /usr/src/chkrootkit-$VERSION/chkrootkit ) | # Binary
grep 'INFECTED|Vulnerable' # Only get found issues
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    /bin/mail -s 'CHROOTKIT Weekly Run ($SERVERNAME)' $EMAIL # Send EMail
fi
```

grep returns a non-zero exit code if it finds a match, 0 if it does not.  We just need to check the last return value (which is grep's return value), and conditionally send the mail based on that.

Comment: You miss the pipe between `grep` and `mail`.